# show alert php to axios

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I want to alert something in php to axios but it doesn't work.

```
axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(function(res) {
  alert("Successfully enrolled.\nPress ok to go back");

})
.catch(function(error) {
  alert("error");
})
```

php code

```
if($bal>=2500) {

} else {
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("insufficient balance")';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

I want it to alert if `$bal` is less than 2500 but the alert wont appear.

Comment: Right now this has two misconceptions. 1) You are not handling the value of the response at all (when the promise resolves) and 2) if you would, then you're better off to "create" the alert in your Javascript (e.g. when handling the response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way to make this work.
Your Javascript could look like this:

```
axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(function(res) {
  if(res.data.success === true){
    alert("Successfully enrolled.\nPress ok to go back");  
  }else{
    alert(res.data.message);
  }
)
.catch(function(error) {
  alert("error");
})
```

PHP

```
$response = array();
if($bal>=2500) {
  $response['success'] = true;
  $response['message'] = 'All ok';
} else {
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['message'] = 'insufficient balance';
}
//this assumes that this is the only thing returned from PHP when making the ajax call.
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I get an undefined alert

Comment: What does `res.data` return?

Comment: it returns false

Comment: Then there's probably something else wrong. See https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema (data property should not return false).

Comment: it works now, the error comes from my code where I echo something. anyway thanks!